# android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

Ao rodar minha aplicação, aparece este erro:

> 05-28 05:33:33.773: E/AndroidRuntime(28824): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.exemploactionbar/br.exemploactionbar.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView.

Minha classe *Adapter*:

```
public class NoticeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Notice> itemList;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public NoticeAdapter(List<Notice> itemList, Context ctx) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = ctx;       
    }

    public int getCount() {
        if (itemList != null)
            return itemList.size();
        return 0;
    }

    public Notice getItem(int position) {
        if (itemList != null)
            return itemList.get(position);
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (itemList != null)
            return itemList.get(position).hashCode();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(view == null) {           
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_notice, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view.setTag(holder);

            holder.tvId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.tvDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
            holder.tvPtime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.publication_time);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvId.setText(itemList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.tvDesc.setText(itemList.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.tvPtime.setText(itemList.get(position).getPublicationTime());

       return view;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvId;
        TextView tvDesc;
        TextView tvPtime;
    }

    public List<Notice> getItemList() {
        return itemList;
    }

    public void setItemList(List<Notice> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

}
```

Meu *Fragment* com a *ListView*:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
private List<Notice> result = new ArrayList<Notice>();
private NoticeAdapter adpt;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ListView lView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_notice, container, false);        

    JsonArrayRequest jReq = new JsonArrayRequest("http://192.168.1.101:3000/notices",
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            Notice notice = new Notice();
                            notice.setId(response.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"));
                            notice.setPicture(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("picture"));
                            notice.setPublicationTime(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("publication_time"));
                            notice.setReducedDescription(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("reduced_description"));
                            notice.setReference(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("reference"));
                            notice.setTitle(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
                            result.add(notice);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Falha com a conexão de internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    adpt.setItemList(result);
                    adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).add(jReq);
    adpt = new NoticeAdapter(result, this.getActivity());
    lView.setAdapter(adpt); 

    return lView;
}
}
```

Minha lista xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/publication_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Estou iniciando no desenvolvimento Android, por isso não tenho muita noção do que pode estar errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro se deve ao facto de você estar a tentar "transformar" um *LinearLayout* em uma *ListView*.

O método `onCreateView()` serve para informar a classe *Fragment* qual o *layout* ela deve utilizar que, neste caso, é `R.layout.list_notice`.
Por outro lado você necessita de ter uma referência à *ListView* que está dentro do *Layout*.

O que está a fazer nesta linha:

```
ListView lView = (ListView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_notice, container, false);
```

Tem de ser feito em duas:

```
//Primeiro construir o Layout
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_notice, container, false);
// depois obter a referência da ListView
ListView lView = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

O método deve retornar o *Layout* e não a *ListView*:
altere

```
return lView;
```

para

```
return view;
```

Comment: fiz as alterações, mas o erro ainda persiste.

Comment: Qual o nome *XML* que tem a *ListView*

Comment: Por lapso coloquei `View view = (ListView) inflater.inflate(...` mas tem de ser `View view = inflater.inflate(...`

Comment: deu certo, o app executou. Mas ele não renderizou a listview com o JSON. Há algo de errado no Fragment?

Comment: Estou executando o app pelo meu celular, e utilizando o wifi, para requisitar o JSON, que está no meu notebook. Será que o erro está aí?

Comment: Como isso já é outro problema sugiro que crie outra pergunta. Antes de o fazer verifique se está a ser retornado algo do serviço.

Comment: A criação da listview, do adapter e do  request com o volley estão certas, né?

Comment: Lamento mas não posso ajudar pois nunca usei o *Volley".

Comment: será que terei de implementar algum outro método do Fragment, para a lista, para ela ser exibida? Tipo o método onclick alguma coisa e etc?

Comment: Verifique se o método `onResponse()` está ser chamado e se a variável `response` tem alguma coisa

Comment: posso testar com o Toast? ou o System.out?

Comment: Pode com Toast.

Comment: Testei com o Toast, não apareceu nada. Acho que ele não está conseguindo criar a ListView, não pela requisição. Será que falta algum método a ser implementado?

Comment: Parece que o problema é como o *volley* está a ser utilizado. Como eu nunca o utilizei, não posso ajudar.